# Why are two class files created on compiling?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I knew that when a class has an inner class then this class will be compiled to two class files. Today I have codes as below

```
public class GenericDeserializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cityPageLoadJson = "{\"count\":2,\"pageLoad\":[{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"HAN\"},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"SGN\"}]}";
        Type type = new TypeToken<GenericResult<City>>() {
        }.getType();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        GenericResult<City> cityPageLoad = gson.fromJson(cityPageLoadJson, type);
        for (City city : cityPageLoad.getPageLoad()) {
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(city));
        }
    }

}
```

Although the above one has no inner class, java compiler still creates two class files:

```
GenericDeserializer.class
GenericDeserializer$1.class
```

Using `Java Decompiler` tool, I see content of the second

```
package net.tuandn.training.lesson.gson;

import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import net.tuandn.training.model.City;
import net.tuandn.training.model.GenericResult;

final class GenericDeserializer$1 extends TypeToken<GenericResult<City>>
{
}
```

Could anybody please explain why this class is created?
And when are multiple class files created on compiling?

Thank a lot!

Comment: Thank for all answers! And how about the second question? Please let me know all cases!

Comment: Updated in my answer.

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry, I wonder one more thing that if class has no inner class, including inner anonymous classes, is it possible to have multiple generated class files on compiling? Do you understand me? sorry for my English!!!

Comment: No that's not possible. A single class will result in a single class file only.

Comment: @RohitJain That's answer I need. Thank you for very detailed answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new TypeToken<GenericResult<City>>() {
}
```

creates an anonymous inner class. Anonymous inner classes, just like inner classes are compiled to separate class files. Since anonymous class don't have name, that is why *numbers* are used to generate unique names for each such classes. The number you see there after `$` is the numbering for that anonymous class, as they come in order in your enclosing class.

If you use more anonymous classes like that, the number will increment by `1`. So for more anonymous classes, the generated class files would look like:

```
GenericDeserializer$1.class
GenericDeserializer$2.class
GenericDeserializer$3.class
GenericDeserializer$4.class
....
```

For inner classes however, the value after the `$` is the name of the inner class, as you already would have noticed.

> And when are multiple class files created on compiling?

Yes, those classes are generated, when you compile your top-level class.

Answer (score 5):

Two class files are generated because you are using an `anonymous` class in the following statement:

```
    TypeToken<GenericResult<City>>() {
    .....
    }
```

Each anonymous class file uses the same name as of the container class and appends a $1/$2 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Simple enough, your decompiled class shows

```
final class GenericDeserializer$1 extends TypeToken<GenericResult<City>>
```

So you have a `TypeToken<GenericResult<City>>` somewhere.

Looking through your code we see

```
Type type = new TypeToken<GenericResult<City>>() { /* anonymous inner class */ }.getType();
```

There's an anonymous inner class declaration there which will therefore get its own class file with `$X` suffix.